# `enumitem` package can't be used in conjunction with `numprint` (or how to set enumerate item has the type of 01, 02, etc.)

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want get a enumerate list has shape *01*, *02*, etc. The LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}
\nplpadding{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\numprint{\theenumi}]
\item Hello, world!
\end{enumerate}
```

is good, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{numprint}
\begin{document}
\nplpadding{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\numprint{\theenumi},leftmargin=*]
\item Hello, world!
\end{enumerate}
```

not.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following in the preample seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@savearabic\@arabic
\def\thenprt@mantissa@digitsbefore{\@savearabic\c@nprt@mantissa@digitsbefore}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Or, without numprint, `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ifnum\value{enumi}<10 0\fi\arabic{enumi}}` and all `enumerate` environments will use that style.